# php for loop using i to declare variable names

Tags: php, loops

I would like to create a loop that names the variables based on i so it should be $l_name0, $lname1, etc. This is what I tried to do, however it just looped forever and did not work.

```
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
    $L_NAME.$i='name'.$i;
    $L_AMT.$i='amt'.$i;
    $L_QTY.$i='qty'.$i;
    echo $L_NAME.$i;
}
```

Any ideas how I can do this?

Comment: Is there a reason why you need them as variables? It's much easier to do this in an array!

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to do what you're trying to do. This is what arrays are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is what you did wrong

```
for ($i=0; $i<=2; $i++) {
    ${'L_NAME'.$i} = 'name'.$i;
    ${'L_AMT'.$i} = 'amt'.$i;
    ${'L_QTY'.$i} = 'qty'.$i;
    echo $L_NAME.$i;
}
```